# How to dynamically define window name variables

Tags: python, variables, pyqt

I need to put window id in window variable name.

I need to dynamically create few windows with the coordinates tables and be able to refer to each of them. 
When I use this code from below I can only call the last made window. 
I tried to define windows this way:

```
    getattr(self, "tb_points%i" % i) = QtGui.QMainWindow()
```

But it gives me an error:

```
    SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
tables = conn.execute("select id from points group by table_id").fetchall()
for i in range(len(tables)):
    tab_id = unicode(tables[i][0])
    q = conn.execute("select * from points where tab_id='"+tab_id+"'").fetchall()
    self.tb_points = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    self.tv_points = QtGui.QTableView()
    self.tv_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(q), 7, self)
```

I want to be able to call, for example:
self.tv_points5.setModel(self.tv_model5)
self.tb_points5.show()
self.tb_points3.hide()

Answer (score 1):

The purely technical answer is that you want `setattr(obj, name, value)`:

```
setattr(self, "tb_points%i" % i, QtGui.QMainWindow())
```

but that's a well known antipattern (how are you going to use attributes that you don't know the name of ?), so a proper design would be to use a list or a dict, ie:

```
self.dyn_windows = []
# unrelated : python "for" loops are of the "foreach" kind
for tab_id in tables:
    # ...
   # for each tab_id, we store a dict referencing the three related windows
   self.dyn_windows.append({
      "tb_points": QtGui.QMainWindow(),
      "tv_points": QtGui.QTableView(),
      "tv_model": QtGui.QStandardItemModel(len(q), 7, self)
      })
```

Also (unrelated but),

1/ [the proper use of the db-api](http://bobby-tables.com/) is:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
# nb: the exact placeholder depends on your db vendor
cursor.execute("select * from xxxx where tab_id=%", [tab_id])
```

2/ I can't get give a working example without knowing your db schema and what exactly you're trying to to but if what you want is a list of "table_id" (or is this "tab_id" ???) : number of points", there's certainly a much better way using aggregations, ie `"select tab_id, count(*) from points group by tab_id"`